# jQuery press link x times then do this?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a link which I load a specific div with, but I would like it to load another div if I press it the third time. How can this be done?

I guess you would do something like defining a variable which is 0, and when it's 3 do something else. I know how to this quite simple stuff in PHP but really don't have good jQuery experience.

To be basic, what I want is something like this:  click, click, click (new function)

This is my current js code:

```
$(".nav").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
                    
        $.get(this.href, function(data) {
            
                $(this).html(data).fadeIn("fast");
        }); 
});
```

Comment: What should happen on the fourth click? What on the sixth? Do you want to create a cycle, like `a a b a a b...`?

Comment: From what I read it's like triple-clicking then action. So yes I suppose it's cycling. (But I am not the OP so...)

Comment: That is what i meant, and "can poyrazoğlu" has answered my question perfectly fine, i've solved the script thanks to that simple but brilliant input. Really appreciate you taking interest in my problem! :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If there is a single div, just declare a global variable like `var counter = 0;` and then in code increment counter on click event `counter++` and check if it is 3, and if it is 3, perform the action like `if(counter == 3) { /*your action*/ }`

Comment: If you wanted this to happen with multiple elements on a page, it could be useful to instead create a new attribute on the element being clicked that would hold the current click count.  This would avoid needing many global JS variables on a page just for tracking clicks.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution could be the [`.toggle()` *<sup>[docs]</sup>*](http://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/) function:

```
$(".nav").toggle(handlerA, handlerA, handlerB);
```

where `handlerA` is a reference to the function you want execute on the first to clicks and `handlerB` the one at the third click.

Answer (score 0):

You should not use  a global variable if you do not have to.  Other languages have `static` variables; however, javascript does not. Javascript does have something very similar though. I recommend you use a method more like this, and inside of the function use the `if` statement that can poyrazoglu has suggested.

Example
The easiest way to explain how to do this is with an example. The following example function is called "foo" and it has a static variable called "counter". Each time it is called the variable is incremented and written to the document.

```
function foo() {

    if( typeof foo.counter == 'undefined' ) {
        foo.counter = 0;
    }
    foo.counter++;
    document.write(foo.counter+"<br />");
}
```

When foo() is first called, foo.counter has not yet been defined. The first line in the example function above checks to see if it's not yet defined and if not initialises it with a value.

Calling foo() multiple times like so:

```
foo();
foo();
foo();
foo();
```

would write this to the document:

```
1
2
3
4
```

example taken from this page: http://www.electrictoolbox.com/javascript-static-variables/